# YouTube insert doesn't respect custom default settings for Privacy Settings and Category

Tags: youtube-api

I am using YouTube API version 3 to upload videos. When [default upload settings](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2660027?hl=en) are specified, in our case category and privacy settings, the insert function doesn't seem to use them.

Is there a way to specify these settings in the insert function? Does another API call need to be made to get these default settings and then pass them to the insert function?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, that's a known internal issue. I'll see what I can do to get it resolved. Ideally, you won't have to do anything special and the defaults will just apply to all videos uploaded via the API.